# On what day did Jesus die according to The United Church of God?

Tags: crucifixion, united-church-god

I've read in the internet which say : *[Jesus crucified on Wednesday, not Friday](https://www.ucg.org/the-good-news/jesus-wasnt-crucified-on-friday-or-resurrected-on-sunday-how-long-was-jesus-in-the)*

But then the explanation paragraph in that page confused me.

> the Passover meal was eaten on Tuesday night and Wednesday sundown
> marked the beginning of the "high day"

Next paragraph on the page :

> Jesus, then, was crucified and entombed on a Wednesday afternoon, not
> on Friday.

I break those two paragraphs into like this :

- (A) the Passover meal was eaten on Tuesday night
- (B) Wednesday sundown marked the beginning of the "high day"
- (C) Jesus was crucified and entombed on a Wednesday afternoon

Another quote from the same page :

> Genesis 1:5 tells us quite plainly that God counts a day as beginning
> with the evening

So I make a chart about the days mentioned in A, B and C according to what the article say, something like this :

[image]

So, the thing which confused me, the article say that The High Day is on Wednesday and Jesus was crucified also in Wednesday.

But from the chart, I thought the article should say that Jesus was crucified on Tuesday afternoon, around a few hours before Wednesday (where Wednesday is the High Day / High Sabbath).

Am I missing something here ?

So I hope there is someone here from The United Church of God (or anyone who happen to know The UCD teaching) who can explain it to me.

---

After seeing the chart from Ray....

On the 2nd day of the week:
Last Supper. To make it easier, say that the Last Supper happen at 8pm, not long after the 2nd day of the week begin.

Around 3pm on the 3rd day of the week, Jesus died.

My conclusion :
According to the UCG, the time span from the Last Supper to the death of Christ is more than 24 hours (as seen in the chart).

Please CMIIW.

---

I just found out that the UCG's chart from Ray is from [2021 article](https://www.ucg.org/beyond-today/beyond-today-magazine/good-friday-easter-sunday-it-just-doesnt-add-up-0), which say the Last Supper happen at Tuesday evening. This chart led me to get a conclusion like above.

Coincidently, I've found another UCG's chart which is from [2013 article](https://www.ucg.org/the-good-news/the-chronology-of-the-crucifixion-and-resurrection-of-jesus-christ), which say that the Last Supper happen at Wednesday evening. This chart show that the Last Supper, the trial, crucifixion and time of death, all happen in the same day, which is Wednesday where Wednesday begin at sunset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UCG article [Good Friday + Easter Sunday: It Doesn’t Add Up!](https://www.ucg.org/beyond-today/beyond-today-magazine/good-friday-easter-sunday-it-doesnt-add-up), and other articles in that issue of the magazine, explain why they believe the Crucifixion was on a Wednesday afternoon in AD 31.

It's not as legible as I'd like, but the UCG produced this chart that shows the events aligned with both Roman and Hebrew days:

[image: Aligned Hebrew and Roman calendars showing events]

> But then the explanation paragraph in that page confused me.
>
> > the Passover meal was eaten on Tuesday night and Wednesday sundown marked the beginning of the "high day"

Referring to "the Last Supper" as "the Passover meal" is definitely the cause of the confusion here.
It doesn't make sense for them to have eaten the Passover meal *before* it was slaughtered:

> The animal was slain on the eve of the Passover, on the afternoon of the 14th of Nisan, after the Tamid sacrifice had been slaughtered, i.e., at three o'clock, …
> — [Passover sacrifice - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover_sacrifice#:%7E:text=The%20sacrificial%20animal,-The%20sacrificial%20animal&text=The%20animal%20was%20slain%20on,of%20the%20Temple%20at%20Jerusalem.)

The UCG definitely teaches that Jesus died in the late afternoon on Wednesday, the day of preparation for the Passover, at the same time as the lambs were slaughtered.
This time is very significant, as they believe that the Passover Holiday was instituted to foreshadow the Crucifixion.

As to why that article referred to the supper as the Passover meal, that's a good question.

The various COG organizations *do* celebrate Passover at the beginning (early night) of the 14th (including a footwashing ceremony and their once-a-year bread and wine "communion" ceremony).

The Passover sacrifice was killed and eaten as a simple supper after sunset just after the 14th begins (only the meal, not the day itself is considered holy).
24 hours later, the first day of the Feast of Unleavened Bread (a high holiday) is celebrated for a week.
This holy feast beginning on the 15th became much larger following the return from Babylonian captivity:

> And the children of Israel that were present at Jerusalem kept the feast of unleavened bread seven days with great gladness …
> And the whole assembly took counsel to keep other seven days: and they kept other seven days with gladness.
> For Hezekiah king of Judah did give to the congregation a thousand bullocks and seven thousand sheep; and the princes gave to the congregation a thousand bullocks and ten thousand sheep … .
>
> 2 Chronicles 30:21,23,24.

The supper, the feast on the first day, and the entire festival can all be referred to as "the Passover", as can be the sacrificed meat.

So yes, the "last supper" was *a* Passover meal, but it was the simple ceremonial one, not the large feast(s) of the following days.

[The New Testament Passover, Doctrinal Study Paper](http://streaming.ucg.org/files/papers/UCG-papers-New-Testament-Passover.pdf) provides much much more detail on this topic.

In addition to the above chart, the same issue of the magazine contains this interesting information,
indicating that the idea of the Wednesday Crucifixion and Saturday Resurrection, with a Tuesday/Wednesday night Passover supper were common in the early days of the Church,
though eventually the current Friday/Saturday view of mainstream Christianity prevailed.

> #### Centuries-Old Documents Show Evidence for a Wednesday Crucifixion
>
> Did you know there is additional historical evidence for a Wednesday crucifixion?
> Although it was a minority position and ran against the prevailing teachings of the Roman church,
> some early historical documents acknowledge a Tuesday night Passover, a Wednesday crucifixion
> and a Saturday afternoon resurrection—matching the biblical record.
>
> Around the year 200, a document purporting to pass on apostolic instruction,
> called the Didascalia Apostolorum,
> mentions that the last Passover of Jesus Christ and His disciples was on a Tuesday night.
>
> This document states: “For when we had eaten the Passover on the third day of the week at even
> [Tuesday evening], we went forth to the Mount of Olives; and in the night they seized our Lord
> Jesus. And the next day, which was the fourth of the week [Wednesday], He remained in ward
> in the house of Caiaphas the high priest” (emphasis added throughout).
>
> Paradoxically, the text goes on to mention that Jesus was crucified on a Friday—showing
> great confusion about the dates, for the biblical account clearly states that Christ was
> crucified in the daylight period following the night of that Passover meal and arrest.
> Nonetheless, the document demonstrates that Passover was then understood by some
> to have been on Tuesday evening, which would place the crucifixion on the next day, Wednesday.
>
> Epiphanius (A.D. 367-403), the bishop at Salamis, wrote that “Wednesday and Friday are
> days of fasting up to the ninth hour because, as Wednesday began the Lord was arrested and
> on Friday he was crucified.”
> As we can see, even though the prevailing view was that Friday was the day of the crucifixion,
> Wednesday was known as the day of Christ’s arrest
> (happening as it did in the early predawn hours that day).
>
> By the fifth century, Easter Sunday celebrations were widespread.
> However, a church historian of the time named Socrates notes in a section of his history
> titled “Differences of Usage in Regard to Easter” that some Christians celebrated
> the resurrection on the Sabbath rather than on Sunday.
> As he put it, “Others in the East kept that feast on the Sabbath indeed.”
>
> Bishop Gregory of Tours (538-594), although himself believing in a Sunday resurrection,
> noted that many believed Jesus rose on the seventh day of the week,
> stating, “In our belief the resurrection of the Lord was on the first day,
> and not on the seventh as many deem.”
>
> So rather than a monolithic acceptance of the Good Friday–Easter Sunday scenario,
> there was confusion about the timing of Christ’s crucifixion in early centuries.
> Moreover, these historical records show that a minority of Christians during
> that time understood the biblical timing of a Tuesday evening Passover,
> a Wednesday crucifixion and a late Saturday afternoon resurrection.
>
> — Mario Seiglie
> — [March–April Beyond Today Magazine](https://www.ucg.org/beyond-today/beyond-today-magazine/beyond-today-magazine-march-april-2023)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Ray. From the chart, am I correct to conclude that according to UCG, Jesus still experience one more night which is on the Preparation Day, after the night before He had the Last Supper with His disciplies ? Because at first I thought : _the Last Supper, the trial, the crucifixion and the time of death ---> all happen in the same day (based on that a day count is from sunset to sunset)._ That's why I confuse why UCG's link said the crucifixion happen on the next day.

Comment: @karma, Preparation Day was Tuesday sunset through Wednesday sunset. People began it with the Passover *supper* and then spent the day making sure all their homes were free of yeast and preparing food for the Passover *feast* that began after sunset on Wednesday. So, Jesus died the next day after the Supper, where "next day" refers to the daylight part of the same day (Tuesday), and was buried just before the High Sabbath began at sunset (Wednesday). ¶ Jumping back and forth between the Roman and Hebrew definitions of when a day begins definitely makes things confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Ray. You wrote :  _Preparation Day was Tuesday sunset through Wednesday sunset_. Am I correct if in the UCG pov, they call that span of time is Wednesday ? For example, if it's Friday sunset through Saturday sunset, then the UCG call that span of time is Saturday ? in the common term of day,  _Jesus died the next day after the Supper_, then that "next day" is Wednesday. But in UCG's pov, the Last Supper, trial, crucifixion, time of death, it all happened in the same day which is Wednesday. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Btw, I agree with your last paragraph. That's why I put my mind to think according to what UCG think, which for example : "if UCG say Tuesday, then that Tuesday begin from (to make it simple) 6.01pm, not 12.01am". Another example : if the current date and time is Friday the 13th 6.30pm, I thought the UCG will not say "today is Friday the 13th", but they will say "today is Saturday the 14th". But it turn out, UCG's article mixed it between the Roman and Hebrew definitions.

Comment: @karma asks "*Am I correct if in the UCG pov, they call that span of time is Wednesday*"? It would be loose usage, but yes, it would include the preceding 6 hours of darkness. This is similar to how in English you might say "*I worked until 2am on Friday*", when 2am was actually on Saturday. Everyone knows what you really meant, and it gets confusing only if one thinks about it. *TV Guide* used to list programs like that. ¶ Consider "Wednesday" as a convenient way of saying "the third day of the week", with everyone understanding that it began at 6pm the night before.

Comment: Thank you once again for the explanation, Ray.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the new information, I've updated my answer to cover two scenarios from the United Church of God (UCG) of which I am not a member.

### SCENARIO ONE

Based on the OP chart from about 4 years ago

Passover Tuesday Nisan 14, Last Supper eaten after sunset as 14th began in evening.

There is confusion on what is meant by the 14th at evening.  It should mean after sunset from the 13th ending as the 14th begins.  Instead, UCG implies it is modern time of the 14th evening after sunset, but before midnight.

Sunset, Passover 14th ends and Wednesday the 15th Feast of Unleavened Bread (high day) begins.  Christ is crucified and entombed on the 15th.

Tuesday, Last Supper, 14th

Wednesday, 15th High Day, Christ entombed

### SCENARIO TWO

Based on Ray's chart from 2023

Sunset, 13th ends, 14th Passover begins Wednesday

Passover 14th Wednesday, Last Supper, arrested

14th Nisan about midnight Jesus arrested in garden

14th Nisan early morning Jesus tried, beaten, hung on cross

14th Nisan Jesus dies, taken down from cross, entombed

Sunset

15th Nisan Thursday Feast of Unleavened Bread begins

So, it appears their events remain the same, but they shifted by one day the dating (14th, 15th).  In the first scenario, Passover is on Tuesday (Last Supper) and Feast of Unleavened Bread is on Wednesday (burial).  In the second scenario, Passover is on Wednesday (Last Supper and burial) and Feast of Unleavened Bread is on Thursday.

Hope that clarifies.

PS The [Didascalia Apostolorum](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/didascalia.html) explains its timeline from Passover (Last Supper and arrest on Tuesday) to burial on Friday.  It's not "paradoxical".  See Chapter XXI, verse 13.  This is UCG's first scenario.  Eat in evening (after sunset) of the 14th Tuesday.

Comment: @RayButterworth I've revised my answer based on your chart.

Comment: The Living Church of God, which has a similar origin to the UCG, explicitly says: "*In the time of Christ, the Jews killed the Passover lamb the afternoon of Nisan 14 at about the hour Christ, the Lamb of God, died at the hands of the Romans.*" ([Easter or Passover: Which Is for Christians? | Tomorrow's World](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/magazines/2011/march-april/easter-or-passover-which-is-for-christians#:~:text=the%20jews%20killed,romans)).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, SLM. You wrote : according to the UCG, on Wednesday, 15th, Jesus was arrested, crucified. I am sorry as I still don't understand, because based on the chart from Ray, to me it seems that according to the UCG, Wednesday is the 14th ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: @RayButterworth, thank you for the comment and link. I've read the link you provide: _Christ's last supper took place at the beginning of Nisan 14_. But the chart from  you, it leads me to conclude that the Last Supper took place at the beginning of Nissan 13 ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma it appears to me UCG changed their timeline.  The OP posts something from about 4 years ago, while Ray posts something from this year.  In any event, I'll try to reexplain both answers.

Comment: @SLM, thank you for your explanation. I think now I realize my mistake which when UCG say the name of the day, I shouldn't put in my mind that in UCG point of view that day begins at sunset (say 6.01pm). I should still think that day begin at midnight (say 12.01am).